# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax.microedition.io.Connector

Tags: android, ksoap2

I am trying to consume a .net web service, and get the following error when I run it(debug) from my phone

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax.microedition.io.Connector

I get the error when I make the call to the transport object

```
ht.call(SOAP_ACTION, soapEnvelope);
```

while in the eclipse ide, the (context sensitive model) does not show this in the object model when i try to add it i only see javax.microedition.khronos.* , no javax.microedition.io, which confuses me more.

When I try to debug this in the emulator, I only get a VerifyError

```
        private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://ikonicsoft.com/CheckTrial";
private static final String METHOD_NAME = "CheckTrial";
private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://ikonicsoft.com";
private static final String URL = "http://ikonicsoft.com/WebService.asmx";

     SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE,METHOD_NAME);
    request.addProperty("deviceid", deviceid);

    SoapSerializationEnvelope soapEnvelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    soapEnvelope.dotNet = true;
    soapEnvelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

    HttpTransport ht = new HttpTransport(URL);
    Boolean bValid = false;
    try{
        ht.call(SOAP_ACTION, soapEnvelope);
        Boolean result = (Boolean) soapEnvelope.getResponse(); 

        if((Boolean)result){
            bValid = true;
        }else{
            bValid = false;
        }

    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        bValid = false;

    }
```

let me know if you need more info

thanks in advance

patrick

Comment: Android doesn't provide that class.  Are you trying to import it into your app's jar file?

Comment: how can i add it so i can use the KSOAP2 API?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, it helps to download and install the correct ksoap2 package. I found the correct package for android development at:

[ksoap2-android-assembly-2.4-jar-with-dependencies.jar](http://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/downloads/detail?name=ksoap2-android-assembly-2.4-jar-with-dependencies.jar)

Answer (score 0):

The Android SDK does not provide the `javax.microedition.io` package. Take a look of this for further reference: [Package Index](http://developer.android.com/reference/packages.html)

Comment: so what then do i need to do to be able to use the ksoap api?

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar problem where Android Studio could not recognize all my `org.ksoap2`imports. It was solved by restarting Android Studio.