# How can I overcome the /AndroidRuntime(331): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax.microedition.io.Connector error in Android?

Tags: android, web-services, ksoap2

I am using the ksoap2-android-2.5.2 for SOAP webservices Login like this

```
HttpTransportBasicAuth aht = new  HttpTransportBasicAuth(URL, username , pass);
```

When I run the program I get the following exception.

```
02-08 16:57:27.014: E/AndroidRuntime(331): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
                                                javax.microedition.io.Connector
```

How can I get that class to our KSOAP2 Library?

Comment: possible duplicate  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3072683/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-javax-microedition-io-connector

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably not using the correct kSoap package for Android.

See this post: [java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax.microedition.io.Connector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3072683/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-javax-microedition-io-connector) and the following [link](http://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/downloads/detail?name=ksoap2-android-assembly-2.4-jar-with-dependencies.jaror-javax-microedition-io-connector)

Answer (score 1):

This is error can also be raised if you have more than one Activity and if you try to access one Activity without Registering in the AndroidManifest.xml file. So make sure that you have registered all your Activity class under this xml file. eg. if u have an activity called Act you will register as

```
<application ...............>
   ----------
   ----------
    <activity android:name=".Act2" /> here goes your registration.    
</application>
```

Answer (score 0):

This class is not in android, its in j2me.