# KSOAP2 library with HttpTransportBasicAuth and javax.microedition.io.Connector?

Tags: android, soap, ksoap2

IS There Any KSOAP2 Library With Basic Authentication AND javax.microedition.io.Connector.

In My project I want To connect my SAP SOAP web-services with Android SOAP services by using KSOAP2.

Comment: possible duplicate of [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9376866/how-can-i-overcome-the-androidruntime331-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-jav). You already got answers and links, please try to read them instead of spamming the question over and over.